# Normal matrices which are products of two symmetric positive definite matrices

Tags: matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are real-valued symmetric positive definite matrices, and if $AB$ is normal, i.e., $AB(AB)^T=(AB)^TAB$ (alternatively, $AB^2A=BA^2B$), then how does one prove that $AB=BA$ (i.e., $AB$ is symmetric).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for $A,B$ positive semi-definite. You have, since $XY$ and $YX$ have the same spectrum, 
$$
\sigma(AB)=\sigma(A^{1/2}A^{1/2}B)=\sigma(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})\subset[0,\infty). 
$$
So $AB$ is normal with real spectrum, thus selfadjoint.

The matrix $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ is positive definite, since 
$$
v^*A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}v=(A^{1/2}v)^*BA^{1/2}v\geq0. 
$$