# Let $A $ and $B$ be real symmetric matrices of order $n$, satisfying $A^2B=ABA.$ Proof that $AB=BA.$

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

Let $A $ and $B$ be real symmetric matrices of order $n$, satisfying $A^2B=ABA.$ Proof that $AB=BA.$
I only find that $A^2B=BA^2=ABA.$ Then I don't know what to do next.Can you help me solve this puzzle?

Comment: How did you show that $A^2B=BA^2$? Compare also with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3368928/normal-matrices-which-are-products-of-two-symmetric-positive-definite-matrices?noredirect=1).

Comment: Multiply the initial relation by $A^{-1}$ on the left.

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ invertible?

Comment: Hint: you can assume that $A$ is diagonal.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this problem. Method 1: prove that $B$ commutes with $A^3$ and argue that $A=p(A^3)$ for some polynomial $p$. Method 2: prove that $\ker(A)$ and $\ker(A)^\perp$ are invariant subspaces of both $A$ and $B$; then prove that $AB=BA$ on these two subspaces. Method 3: first, show that $A$ commutes with $AB-BA$; then apply Jacobson's lemma and note that $AB-BA$ is skew-symmetric.

Comment: $A^2B=ABA \implies A(AB) = A(BA) \implies A^{-1}A(AB) = A^{-1}A(BA) \implies AB=BA$ surely?

Comment: @tai Of course, the result is obvious when $A$ is invertible, but here we don't know this.

Comment: Another option: write out $\big \Vert AB-BA\big\Vert_F^2=\text{trace}\big(BA^2B\big) +\text{trace}\big(AB^2A\big)-\text{trace}\big(BABA\big)-\text{trace}\big(ABAB\big)=0$ where the zero comes from applying the identity in OP to the 2 subtracted items (as well as cyclic property of trace).

Comment: @user1551 How did you proof this puzzle using Method 3 ? Could you explain it in more detail to make it an answer？

Comment: @Gyh Any nilpotent skew-symmetric matrix must be zero.

Comment: One more option (loosely related to @user1551 's method 2). Define bilinear form $\langle \mathbf x,\mathbf y\rangle:= \mathbf x^T (ABA)\mathbf y$. Now select non-zero $\mathbf v,\mathbf w$, coming from 2 (arbitrary) distinct eigenspaces of $A$.  The identity in the OP also tells us we can compute $\langle \mathbf v, \mathbf w\rangle$ two different ways, inferring $\langle \mathbf v, \mathbf w\rangle = 0 =\mathbf v^T B\mathbf w$.  Conclude $B$ respects $A's$ eigenspaces $\implies AB=BA$.  (The case $A=\lambda I$ trivially holds.)

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is invertible or $A=0$ then it is obvious. Assume now that $A\ne 0$ and $\det A=0$.

$A$ is symmetric and hence diagonalizabe by an orthnormal matrix $U$. Set $A=U^{-1}LU$, where$L$ is diagonal. Expressing $L$ and $\hat B=UBU^{-1}$ (which is also symmetric) in block form,
$$
L=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}D & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}
\right),\qquad
UBU^{-1}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}B_1 & B_2 \\ B_3 & B_4\end{array}
\right)=\hat B,
$$
where $D$ is diagonal and invertible, we have
$$
U^{-1}L^2\hat B U=U^{-1}L^2UB=A^2B=ABA=U^{-1}LUBU^{-1}LU=U^{-1}L\hat BLU
$$
or
$$
L^2\hat B=L\hat BL
$$
or
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}D^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}B_1 & B_2 \\ B_3 & B_4\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}D & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}B_1 & B_2 \\ B_3 & B_4\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}D & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}
\right)
$$
or
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}D^2B_1 & D^2B_2 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}DB_1D & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}
\right).
$$
Hence $B_2=0$ and $DB_1=B_1D$, and also $B_3=B_1^T=0$, in which case
$$
BA=U^{-1}\hat BUU^{-1}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}D & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}
\right)U=
U^{-1}\hat B\left(
\begin{array}{cc}D & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}
\right)U=U^{-1}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}B_1 & 0 \\ 0 & B_4\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}D & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}
\right)U=U^{-1}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}B_1D & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}
\right)U=U^{-1}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}DB_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}
\right)U=U^{-1}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}D & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}B_1 & 0 \\ 0 & B_4\end{array}
\right)U=U^{-1}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}D & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}
\right)\hat BU=U^{-1}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}D & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}
\right)UBU^{-1}U=AB
$$

Answer (score -1):

Since $A^{2}B=ABA$ and both these matrices are symmetric, we obtain $A^{2}B=BA^{2}$.

Multiply by $A$ on both sides to obtain $BA^{3}=A^{3}B$ (Using the relation $ABA=A^{2}B$).

Carrying this process out repeatedly, we see that $A^{n}B=BA^{n} \forall n \geq 2$.

Using Cayley-Hamilton, we see that the characteristic polynomial kills $A$, i.e. $p(A)=0$. So, now we can write $A$ as a linear combination of $I$ and $A^{n}$ for $n \geq 2$. Using the fact we proved above, we're done.

Comment: From $ABA=A^2B$ I get $A^2BA=A^3B$ not $BA^3=A^3B\,.$

Comment: $BA^2=A^2B$ implies $BA^3=A^2BA$, but $A(ABA)=A(A^2B)$.

Comment: This does not always work, because the coefficient of $A$ in the characteristic and minimal polynomials of $A$ may be zero. Consider $A=\pmatrix{1\\ &-1}$ for instance.

Comment: I think there's a fix for that. Since A is symmetric, the minimal polynomial would have only distinct roots. This implies both the constant and the coefficient of A cannot be zero. Now, if the coefficient of A is zero, just multiply the min poly by A and you have a relation with higher powers of A.

Comment: Yes, it's a valid fix.